# spirngframework.ws HttpComponentsMessageSender - how to set maximum connectons per any host?

Tags: java, spring, apache-httpclient-4.x, spring-framework-beans

I am migrating from apache httpclients-3.x to 4.x and thus have to update *org.springframework.ws.transport.http.CommonsHttpMessageSender* to *org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpComponentsMessageSender*.

My previous spring-beans.xml configuraion was this:

```xml
<bean id="signHttpSender" class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpComponentsMessageSender">
    <property name="maxConnectionsPerHost">
      <props>
        <prop key="*">20</prop>
      </props>
    </property>
  </bean>
```

"*" character allowed to set maximum connections for any given host.

If I try the same configuration, I receive *java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Host name may not be null*. Looking at the HttpComponentsMessageSender code I see no way of limiting number of cnnections for any host, just total amount of connections or max connections per certain host.

How could I achieve the same result as by using "*" in CommonsHttpMessageSender?

Answer (score 0):

I found some dirty solution which works. This definitely is wrong but I post it until the proper one is found just in case it wil help someone.

```xml
<bean id="signHttpSender" class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpComponentsMessageSender">
    <property name="credentials" value="#{signHttpSender.getHttpClient()
                     .getConnectionManager().setDefaultMaxPerRoute(20)}"/>
  </bean>
```

You can use any other property which is not initialised and is null. This solution won't work if You have to give values to every property though.